# `return value' from Constructor Exception in Java?

Tags: java, exception, instantiation

Take a look that the following code snippet:

```
A a = null
try {
  a = new A();
} finally {
  a.foo();  // What happens at this point?
}
```

Suppose A's constructor throws a runtime exception. At the marked line, am I always guaranteed to get a NullPointerException, or foo() will get invoked on a half constructed instance?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code inside the `try` block contains two distinct operations:

1. Create a new `A` instance.
2. Assign the new instance to a variable named `a`.

If an exception is thrown in step 1, step 2 will not be executed.
Therefore, you will always get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Therefore write it as `final A a = new A(); try { ... } finally { a.foo(); }`. And if it needs an exception caught add **another** try block around the lot.

Comment: or if you are unsure of the state of the `a` reference in the finally block, just wrap `a.foo()` with `(if a!=null)`

Answer (score 6):

If `new A()` raises an exception, you'll always get a NullPointerException because the assignment to `a` won't happen.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would always get an NPE at the marked line. 
The assignment never has a chance to occur.

Answer (score 1):

If the exception occured in the constructor call new A(),That time the object has null value.So the a.foo()
gives the null pointer exception.you can give the condition as if(a!=null){
a.foo();
}